# CentOS7 エラーが標準出力されない場合に強制出力したい

Tags: linux, centos

CentOS7でエラーが標準出力されない場合があります。

例えば、ifupやifdownの結果は、
何も出力されないのですが、実際は正しく動作していないです。

現在は、

```
ifup ppp0 || echo "エラー発生"
```

のようにして、発生していることだけが検知できるようにしています。

何か強制的に標準出力する方法は無いでしょうか？

Comment: エラーの発生時に何らかのメッセージを出力するかはコマンドの実装次第ですし、エラーの発生を検知したいなら直前のコマンドの終了ステータスを調べる方法もありますが、今回の目的はあくまで「エラー出力を受け取りたい」ということですか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。
なるほど、「エラー出力は、ifupに存在しなければ、受け取れないけれども、
終了ステータスを確認すれば良い」ということですね。

はい、そちらで十分だと思います。
正常終了したのか、途中終了したのかが知れれば、
その後の処理を変えられるためです。
(前述の方法でも途中終了であることは分かりますが、何かステータスの情報が得られれば、
それによって処理を分岐したりできそうです)

Comment: "何も出力しないコマンドが正常に終了したのかエラーが発生したのか判断する方法はありますか？"みたいなタイトルにすると適切な回答が得られると思います。

Comment: たまたま例に挙げられたものは[RHEL 8 (CentOS 8)のifup / ifdownの中身はnmcliだった話](https://tech-mmmm.blogspot.com/2020/02/rhel-8-cent-os8ifup-ifdownnmcli.html) の中身を見るとシェルスクリプトのようですが。

Comment: ifup ppp0 || echo $? とすれば、エラー原因を調べるとっかかりになるかもしれません。

Answer (score 1):

コメントでのやり取りも踏まえて、真にやりたいことは「`ifup` 実行時に何らかのエラーがあった場合にそれを検知して受け取りたい」だろうという前提で回答してみます。

---

`ifup` コマンドに限らず、Linux コマンドは終了時に **終了ステータス** と呼ばれるコマンド実行の成否を表す特殊変数 `$?` に値を設定するのが一般的です。

- 正常終了時: `0`
- 異常終了時: `1` (またはコマンドやエラーの種類に応じて `0` 以外の数値)

`ifup` コマンドは (コメントでも指摘のある通り) 中身を覗くとシェルスクリプトになっており、動作を追っていくと別のスクリプトを順々に呼び出していますが、終了ステータスについては上記説明と同じ値を設定しているようなので、この値を元に判定すれば良さそうです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
とても良く理解できました。
シンプルでまさに求めていた挙動です。